# htaccess problem with empty string in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want users to only be able to access domain.com or domain.com/. Anything afterwards, even domain.com/index.php, should redirect to domain.com.

I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ 404.php?cp=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem is that the parameter is never empty. Therefore 404.php is always called. If I go to domain.com, it redirects to `404.php?cp=index.php`. If I remove the index.php rule, it redirects to `404.php?cp=index.php`. If I delete the index.php file and rule, I get a server error. If I allow `index.php`, then it works and redirects to index.php but that's not what I want. Users shouldn't be able to call index.php, or any file, or add anything after the domain even if index.php is ultimately called. So basically I want to allow an internal redirect to index.php only if it was instructed by the htaccess file, not by the user.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So basically I want to allow an internal redirect to index.php only if it was instructed by the htaccess file, not by the user. How can I fix this?

To present `index.php` for request to `http://example.com` you don't need a rewrite rule, just use `DirectoryIndex` directive like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Now to rewrite to `404.php` if users enter anything after `example.com/` you can check `THE_REQUEST` based condition. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

So combining it all, your full suggested .htaccess should look like this:

```bash
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# http -> https redirection (note there is no REQUEST_URI)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]

# redirect anything after example.com/ to example.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[^\s?]
RewriteRule ^(?!(index|404)\.php$).+ /404.php?cp=$0 [L,NC,QSA,R=302]
```

However do keep in mind that last rule will also redirect any request for resources such as images, stylesheets and js files to `https://example.com`

Comment: Thank you very much. That works in redirecting to index.php, but I want to redirect everything to 404.php except domain.com and domain.com/. Sorry, that one sentence summary was not good enough :)

Comment: ok try my updated code now

Comment: Thank you, but it behaves weirdly now. It redirects to folders over my hosted file (I have shared hosting). So it's redirecting to "url.com/htdocs/<the folder I have access to through FTP/404.php?cp=htdocs/<the folder I have access to through FTP/404.php?cp=htdocs/<the folder I have access to through FTP/404.php?cp=" and so on and crashes. When I open my FTP via FileZilla I cannot go into the htdocs folder (only via ssh)

Comment: Sorry I missed leading `/` before `404.php`. Please try now after clearing old browser cache.

Comment: Thank you for your time, done!

Answer (score 1):

The following redirect will redirect any request that is not `/` to `/`. domain.com and domain.com/ are the same thing.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ 
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but that unfortunately does not solve that everything should go to 404.php except domain.com and domain.com/ which should go to index.php.